How can I sync Threejs with HTML?
I have a problem with a website where I am using Threejs. All my problems are solved when I synchronise the scrolling speed of html and canvas. My canvas scrolls much slower than the html, and the divs that are above the models in threejs and are centered over them, are splitting after scrolling ( they are no longer above them perfectly ).
Anyone know how to fix this?
I tried to grab the scrolling speed in js, but it didn't work. I'm wondering about an external library like lenis for example, but I don't know how to add it to threejs and if it would make sense.
